# R ggplot boxplot: order filling variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am generating a number of boxplots, each for a different marker, filled by a categorical variable: 'CR' and 'No CR'.

I want the left box in the plot to be the 'No CR'-fill and the right one 'CR'. Like this one:

[image: good order]

However, for some plots, I get it the other way around (left 'CR' and right 'No CR')
[image: wrong order]

How can I control (order?) which filling category is left and which one is right?

Here is part of my code:

```r
head(df)

#      ID   y   CR
# 1     1    0  No CR
# 2     2    0  No CR
# 3     3    0  CR
# 4     4    4  No CR

ggplot(df, aes(x = CR, y = y)) +
                  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=CR)) +
                  labs(title="Highly differential peptides") + 
                  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#35978f","#D6604D"))+ 
                  stat_compare_means( label.y = maxadn,size=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can relevel your CR variable :

```
df$CR=factor(df$CR,levels=c("No CR","CR"))
```

and then try to replot

Comment: Simple and effective :D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to answer your question thoroughly. First I'll simulate some data:

```r
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame( 
    CR = sample(c("CR", "No CR"), 20, replace=TRUE), 
    y = rpois(20, 2) 
)
```

Then, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997752/reordering-bars-in-ggplot/71998295), you can either set the limits directly:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = CR, y = y)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=CR)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#35978f","#D6604D")) +  
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("No CR", "CR"))
```

[image]

or use factor levels to control the order:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(CR, levels=c("No CR", "CR")), y = y)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=CR)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#35978f","#D6604D")) +  
    labs(x = "CR")
```

[image]

Without any reordering:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = CR, y = y)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=CR)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#35978f","#D6604D"))
```

[image]